# Signing to google cloud with selenium automation failed with error “This browser or app may not be secure.”

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have Dot Net application that run selenium commands for login to GCP via browser (Chrome) web site.

The automation access is now blocked by google. We get an error "This browser or app may not be secured …"

I didn't find any official solution in google documentation. Also the oauth2 protocol authentication is only applies for API access and not for web site access, which is our main requirement for our application.

Your help will be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is something built-in (to Google servers) - cant use Puppeteer either to log onto YouTube studio - happy to be wrong though!

Comment: Could you please explain what you tried to achieve and what didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest updating your selenium drivers / chrome to the latest version. Another option is to `enable less secure apps` to access the account you are working under. More information on that procedure can be found [here](https://hotter.io/docs/email-accounts/secure-app-gmail/).

Answer (score 0):

Users authenticate on the website in different ways. For example [Google Sign In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) or [OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect).

You can check this [Google Identity Platform document](https://developers.google.com/identity/choose-auth) that helps you to setup the OAuthentication for your website.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily bypass the google bot detection with the `undetected-selenium` driver:

```
pip install undetected_selenium
pip install selenium
```

Small script that logs into google account:

Credits: https://github.com/xtekky/google-login-bypass/blob/main/login.py

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#  ---------- EDIT ----------
email = 'email\n' # replace email
password = 'password\n' # replace password
#  ---------- EDIT ----------

driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
url = 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=accountsettings&continue=https://myaccount.google.com%3Futm_source%3Daccount-marketing-page%26utm_medium%3Dgo-to-account-button'
driver.get(url)


wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'identifier'))).send_keys(email)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password'))).send_keys(password)
print("You're in!! enjoy")
```